# C# Attempting to resize an array of objects dynamically WITHOUT using Array.Resize or Lists

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic-arrays

**How can I hardcode exactly what Array.Resize does? To copy the original array into a new one that has the same name and make the old one garbage memory?**

I’m working on a game that stores data from each round into an array of objects that contain the specific data for each round so that it can print out the move history to the user when the game concludes.

However, this is for a college class and I'm not allowed to use Lists or Array.Resize...

I can copy the elements into a new, larger array easily enough with a for loop.

However, the new array has to have a different name than the original, and this messes up all my relevant method calls to access the data within the new array.

And on top of that, because this is a game, it may need to resize the array many times, therefor I need a solution that can work indefinitely (until the user runs out of memory of course)

(And we can't simply initialize the array with more than 10 slots either...)

```
class MarsLanderHistory
{
    RoundInfo[] rounds = new RoundInfo[10];

    int numRounds = 0;

    public void AddRound(int nHeight, int nSpeed)
    {
        if (rounds.Length <= numRounds)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref rounds, rounds.Length + 10);
        }

        RoundInfo newRound = new RoundInfo(nHeight, nSpeed);
        rounds[numRounds] = newRound;
        numRounds++;
    }

    public int NumberOfRounds()
    {
        return numRounds;
    }

    public int GetHeight(int roundNum)
    {
        return rounds[roundNum].GetHeight();
    } 

    public int GetSpeed(int roundNum)
    {
        return rounds[roundNum].GetSpeed();
    } 


    // you'll need other methods in order to make the PrintHistory command work
}

// This is provided to you; you shouldn't need to add anything to it, but
// if you want to you are welcome to do so
class RoundInfo
{
    private int height;
    private int speed;

    #region Accessors
    public int GetHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public void SetHeight(int newValue)
    {
        height = newValue;
    }

    public int GetSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }
    public void SetSpeed(int newValue)
    {
        speed = newValue;
    }
    #endregion Accessors

    public RoundInfo(int h, int s)
    {
        height = h;
        speed = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid Array.Resize()?

Comment: Just create a temp array, copy the values, then assign the temp array to the original.  That's what `Array.Resize` does.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3,references

Comment: I've just got to say that a class that doesn't let you use `List` or `Array.Resize` when you can lookup the source code is beyond silly.

Comment: if it was me i would look up the source for array.resize() and implement it myself.  all Microsoft code is open source remember

Comment: OHHHHH I see, so you're saying if I have an array called rounds[] and a temporary array that's longer called roundsTemp[] I can literally just do "rounds = roundsTemp" to give the new one the same memory address? The solution is so simple I feel dumb haha